# owl-carousel is Not working when its data comes from ajax request in mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify

I have used owl carousel in my shopify store on mobile devices. Data Of owl Carousel is coming from my private app usin ajax request. My owl carousel is not loaded and data is listed as list on mobile and face this error:

[image]

Here Is code which i have used:-

```js
function owl_slider(){
          var owl = $('#shoppinglistDetailMobile .owl-carousel');
          owl.owlCarousel({
            margin: 30,
            loop: true,
            navigation : true,
            autoplay:false,
            autoplayTimeout:3000,
            autoplayHoverPause:true,
            responsive: {
              0: {
                items: 2
              },
              400: {
                items: 2
              },
              600: {
                items: 3
              },
              800: {
                items: 3
              },
              1200: {
                items: 4
              },
              1300: {
                items: 4
              },
              1350: {
                items: 6
              },
              1400: {
                items: 6
              },
              1600: {
                items: 6
              }
            }
          });
  }
    
    
  $('#shoppinglistDetailMobile .owl-carousel').html(htmlDataMobile);

                 owl_slider();
```

This owl_slider function is call at time when my ajax request is success and my data is embeded in div.

Please Help me regarding this. Thanks In advance.

Comment: Add some code here !

Comment: @pedram I have added my code snippet please check

Comment: This error mostly occurred when you didn't include `owl carousel` library, double check this. and be sure you include this exactly before your script.

Comment: @pedram Thanks For reply but i have added owl carousel libaray in my shopify theme.liquid in head. Actually my data comes from another server to shopify in mobile devices so owl carousel is not working in mobile

Comment: No, i don't think this error belong `ajax load data` the problem is `owl carousel` not defined and that's mean something wrong in calling this library. try to change `owl.owlCarousel({` to `$('#shoppinglistDetailMobile .owl-carousel').owlCarousel` and something important, if you want load carousel data via `ajax` this way not working for sure.

Comment: See these 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41106614/how-to-reinitialize-owl-carousel-after-ajax-call | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38920590/owl-carousel-ajax-load | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35838983/owl-carousel-2-dynamic-content-json

Comment: This mean, you should get `data` first then initialize owl carousel